# Return HTML string without quotes

Tags: javascript, string, quotes

I am working on a project that allows to reuse HTML code in a dynamic manner (much like React). In order to create templates I need to return strings with HTML content. To make working with the HTML easier I want to get rid of the Quotation marks all together without getting errors.

How it looks like now:

```
let your_elem = new Element(() => {
   return (
      "<h1>Test</h1>"
   );
}
```

What I am trying to achieve:

```
let your_elem = new Element(() => {
   return (
      <h1>Test</h1>
   );
}
```

I am not sure how React manages to do this.

Comment: React manages to do it with [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html).

Comment: You can make it easier by using tick marks instead of the parentheses... (i.e., `return \`<h1>Test</h1>\``).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React uses [JSX](https://facebook.github.io/jsx/) which is then fed to a transpiler (such as jsx-transform or Babel) to convert it to standard javascript that a browser would understand.

If you don't want to use a transpiler and be able to pass this directly to a browser, one step closer would be to use [`backquote`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
let your_elem = new Element(() => {
   return (`
      <h1>Test</h1>
   `);
}
```

This would allow you multiline javascript string literals that can also contain double quotes:

```
let your_elem = new Element(() => {
   return (`
      <h1 class="foo">Test</h1>
      <div>Test</div>
   `);
}
```

It will also allow you to make it more dynamic by injecting javascript code directly into the template:

```
let className = "foo";
let your_elem = new Element(() => {
   return (`
      <h1 class="${className}">Test</h1>
      <div>Test</div>
   `);
}
```

Comment: I was aware of blockquotes. I guess it's a little overkill to use JSX for this feature so I'll stick to quotes..